# yacc program to accept the string starts with 01 and ends with 10

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, lexical-analysis

```
%{
int yylex(void);
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int yyerror(char* s);
%}

%token ZERO ONE NL

%%

st : ZERO s ZERO NL { printf("Sequence Accepted\n");}
;

s : ONE r
;

r: r ONE
 |
;

%%
int main()
{
    printf("Enter Sequence of Zeros and Ones : \n");
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

int yyerror(char *s)
{
    printf("Sequence Rejected\n");
}
```

This is my yacc file what changes i would make so that it accept the string starting with '01' and ends with '10'

```
%%
st : ZERO ONE s ONE ZERO NL{printf("Sequence Accepted\n");}
;

s : s ZERO
s ONE 
ZERO
ONE
;
%%
```

Comment: Please make an attempt to show that you care about your question being readable. Start by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). (There's a big `?` on the upper right of the input form.)

Comment: I'm so soory its my first question that i asked --- so i dont have any knowledge regarding that... Actually im trying to write a yacc program for accpeting string starting wth '01' and ending with '10' could u please help to do so..

Comment: You have two bison grammar descriptions in your question. Why? What is the purpose of the first one? What do you expect the second one to do? Why did you correctly use `|` in the first example -- at least, I guess it's correct, although I don't know what the purpose of that grammar is -- but in the second grammar you seem to think that you can list alternatives on separate lines. You can't. I'm sure that your course materials include some kind of gentle introduction to Bison; if not, trying reading the [Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Concepts)